# Mounting Windows Phone 8.1 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mount, windows-phone

I've recently installed Ubuntu on my computer, erasing Windows Vista forever. So far, so good: I love the OS!

The only issue for me is my mobile phone, a Nokia Lumia with Windows Phone. Sometimes it works (when it does, it behaves like a USB memory stick); sometimes it doesn't. When it doesn't, Ubuntu shows me this:

> Unable to access “Nokia Lumia 820 (RM 825)”

and

> mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C024%5D” could not be found. Perhaps it has recently been deleted.

What's going on and how can I fix this?